# Is there a way to create a biplot with the psych package using ggplot()

Tags: r, psych

I'm finding it hard to create a biplot in ggplot2 from a principal components analysis done in psych.

```
library(psych)
data("Thurstone")
pca1<-principal(Thurstone, nfactors=2, rotate="varimax")
#install.packages("ggfortify")
library(ggfortify)
autoplot(pca1)
```

Comment: See the manual page `?biplot.psych`: "This will work for objects produced by fa, fa.poly or principal if they applied to the original data matrix." The "Thurstone" data is a correlation matrix. That means the scores on the original data cannot be computed so a biplot is not possible. This would apply to ggplot as well as base graphics biplot functions.